# Timer to refresh form

Tags: c#

I have a form that I want to update every x sec.
To set the sec that I want i used a combobox with 60,120,180,240 and 300
This should determine the sec. 
The timer is running, no problems there. 
But ... I can't set the timer to read howmany sec he must run. And, when the timer hits the sec het should restart, that is also a problem. 
I'm very new in c#, taking lessons etc, but that is something I can't figure out. (sorry for my poor english).
Can I get some help here?
This is what I got sofare.

```
_ticks++;
label1.Text = _ticks.ToString();
if (_ticks == 10)
{
    label1.Text = "Done";
}
```

and this is how I fill the combo

```
this.cmbRefresh.Items.AddRange(new object[] { "OFF", "60", "120", "180", "240", "300" });
```

I know I don't have much, but I don't know where to begin.
thanks in advance

Comment: can you give us more code? I don't understand how your loop and timer works

Comment: also using a timer to fill a textbox/modify one.......can cause quite some problems (as you need to think of: "gui thread", "timer thread", ....

Answer (score 0):

[Handle the `ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged` event.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2) You can do that by selecting the ComboBox, clicking F4 for Properties, switching to the Events tab and double clicking the `SelectedIndexChanged` event.

In the handler use `int.Parse(this.comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString())` to get the amount of seconds and multiply it by a thousand and use `this.timer1.Interval = sec * 1000` to update the interval.

Handle the "OFF" value separately using `if` before parsing to `int`, because `int.Parse` won't work with it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Timer for that:

```
Timer timer = new Timer;
timer.Elapsed += OnTimerEvent;
```

The timer event callback:

```
void OnTimerEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    // Refresh
}
```

Then, when the user changes the combo box, start the timer

```
string t = cmbRefrest.SelectedItem.ToString();
if ("OFF" == t) timer.Enabled = false;
else {
    int timeout = Int32.Parse(t) * 1000;
    timer.Interval = timeout;
    timer.Enabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I imagine you want it to update each time the ComboBox is changed, and for that you can simply create an eventhandler for the "SelectedIndexChanged" event.

```
private void cmbRefresh_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cmbRefresh.Text != "OFF")//If the combobox text is not "OFF"
    {
        timer1.Interval = int.Parse(cmbRefresh.Text) * 1000;//Set the interval to x seconds (value is multiplied by 1000 because timer intervals are set to milliseconds).
    }
    else//If the combobox text is "OFF"
    {
        timer1.Enabled = false;//Stop the timer.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the interval property on the Timer and handle the Timer.Tick and ComboBox SelectedIndexChanged event to update your label. The interval is the amount of time, in milliseconds, the timer will wait until raising its Tick event.

You will need to add logic in here to ensure that the value is an integer.

Combo Change:

```
timer.Interval = Convert.ToInt32(this.cmbRefresh.SelectedValue) * 1000;
```

Handle the Tick and safely update the label.

```
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var thisTimer = sender as Timer;
        if (thisTimer != null)
        {
            _ticks++;
            this.UpdateLabel(_ticks.ToString());
            if (_ticks == 10)
            {
                this.UpdateLabel("Done");
            }                
        }
    }

private void UpdateLabel(string text)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke(new Action(() => this.UpdateLabel(text));
    }
    else
    {
        this.label1.Text = text;
    }
}
```